# FileSystemWatcher in .NET core systemd daemon

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, systemd

I have a .NET core 3.1 "worker" service (like this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-and-systemd/).

I am using the FileSystemWatcher class to watch for new files in a folder and trigger a process for them. The service works as expected in Windows (as a service and running it as a console program), and it works in linux when running it directly in the Terminal.

When starting it as a daemon (`sudo systemctl start {myservice}.service`) it starts, but it doesn't monitor the folder.

Below my worker class.

If I expand the max number of watches in the system it works.

> sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576

**Any ideas why I need to increase the maximum watches?** please note that the folder I am monitoring has about 100 files only (the default is about 8192 max watches).

My concern is that there is something I am not understanding about the class, so I am setting an arbritary high number to the max number of watches, without knowing when that will be reached or why. Also, FileSystemWatcher seems completely unaware of what is going on, so my program can't do anything about it because it doesn't know.

```
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        private FileSystemWatcher _fileSystemWatcher;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Service startup.");
             fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"/myfolder/myfolder2");
            _fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            _fileSystemWatcher.Filter = "*.xml"; 
            _fileSystemWatcher.Created += (e, args) => _logger.LogWarning("StartAsync watcher: {0}", args.FullPath);
            _fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }


        public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Stopping Service");

            await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Service Execute.");
                        
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Keep alive: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(5*60*1000, stoppingToken);
            }

            _logger.LogInformation("Service Execute stopped.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? Did you continue with the FileSystemWatcher  and is it working reliably on both windows and linux?